# Help with MySQL sub query

Tags: mysql

Basically what I have is a comments MySQL table. I have a column called 'parent_id' which tracks if a comment is a reply to another comment.

What I want to do is count all the comments. This was working fine but if you delete a comment and not the replies, it counts them as still active but intact they are deleted.

Here is my MySQL query which at the moment isn't working... Any ideas?

```
SELECT ic.* 
FROM roster_services_items_comments AS ic 
WHERE (SELECT icp.id FROM roster_services_items_comments AS icp 
       WHERE ic.parent_id = '' 
       OR (icp.id = ic.parent_id AND icp.deleted != 0) 
       LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT ic.*, COUNT(icp.parent_id) AS replies_count
FROM roster_services_items_comments AS ic
LEFT JOIN roster_services_items_comments AS icp ON ic.id = icp.parent_id
WHERE ic.deleted != 0
GROUP BY ic.id
HAVING ic.parent_id IS NULL
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the count to not count if a comment doesn't have any replies

Comment: this would count only root comments

Comment: @Yuri No it would count the number of replies for each comment. I don't think we're in a recursive problem here. The way I understand it is that there is only 1 'sublevel' of comments. There is no concept of a reply to a comment's reply and so on. Like the way it is here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a trigger which marks replies of deleted to be deleted

the problem is that you need recursivly check the current comment for possible parents and parent's parents

you can create a recursive function, which determine has it deleted parents or not

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*)
From roster_services_items_comments As ic 
Where ( ic.parent_id = '' And deleted = 0 )
    Or ic.id Not In (
                    Select ic1.parent_id
                    From roster_services_items_comments As ic1
                    Where ic1.deleted = 1
                    )
```

Can parent_id really be an empty string? Wouldn't it make more sense for parent_id to be NULL when it was the top most comment? If that were true we'd have:

```
Select Count(*)
From roster_services_items_comments As ic 
Where ( ic.parent_id Is Null And deleted = 0 )
    Or ic.id Not In (
                    Select ic1.parent_id
                    From roster_services_items_comments As ic1
                    Where ic1.deleted = 1
                    )
```